# Partition Theorem for expectations - why only dependent on value of X and not Y?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation, set-partition

[image: Textbook Explanation]

Hi there,

In my textbook above, there is a theorem stating that the expectation of $E [Y | X]$ is equal to $E[Y]$.

However, the textbook also states that this theorem only depends on the value of $X$. Why not the value of $Y$?

Thanks very much

Comment: This is known as the law of total expectation. Instead of figuring out $Y$, we can condition on values of $X$. This is related to the law of total probability.

Answer (score 1):

> In my textbook above, there is a theorem stating that the expectation of E[Y|X] is equal to E[Y].

That is often known as the Law of Total Expectation, or the Tower Property:

$\qquad\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$.

> However, the textbook also states that this theorem only depends on the value of X. Why not the value of Y?

Your textbook should state that **the conditional expectation** only depends on the value of $X$.

This is for the same reason the unconditional expectation is not dependent on $Y$.

$\mathsf E(Y)$ is a constant.   It does not vary with $Y$ *because* it is the expected value (or *mean* value) of that random variable.

Similarly, $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)$ a function of $X$.   It is the expected value of $Y$ as a function of a given value for $X$.